# Quadratic algorithm for Matrix Chain Multiplication

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, dynamic-programming, matrices

I have an algorithm that supposedly solves the matrix chain multiplication problem in $O(n^2)$ time. I have tested it only on trivial cases and they turned out to be correct.

By no means, am I a genius, but I was wondering if you guys could point out where this algorithm lacks.

The algorithm:

```
Base case:
     MCM(A) = 0;
     MCM(AB) = nrow(A) * ncol(A) * ncol(B)
Otherwise:
     MCM(AB....JK) = min(MCM(B...K) + cost_of_mul(A, B...K),
                     MCM(A...J) + cost_of_mul(A...J, K),
                     MCM(AB) + MCM(C...K) + cost_of_mul(AB, C...K),
                     MCM(A...I) + MCM(JK) + cost_of_mul(A...I, JK));

where MCM is a nxn matrix that stores the minimum number of scalar products needed for the sequence from i to j (MCM[i][j])
```

The rationale behind this is that each grouping takes care of at least two  matrices, and that is being handled when considering the minimum.

Comment: It's already known that this can be done in time $O(n\log n)$ (see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#More_efficient_algorithms)). I guess your angle is that your algorithm trades simplicity for efficiency. However, verifying research isn't something we do here: our scope is answering specific questions and "Is my research correct?" is too open-ended. I suggest you try to _prove_ that your algorithm (a) produces the correct answer and (b) does so in $O(n^2)$ steps. Testing isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm has lower complexity than the straightforward standard version of the dynamic programming solution, because it scans only a (strict) subset of the subproblems it needs to consider.

Say there are $n$ matrices at some point. Your algorithm checks five specific parenthetizations: between first and second, between penultimate and last, etc. It's possible that the optimal parenthetization is between the element at $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor + 1$, for example, but your algorithm doesn't check that.

It's possible that you tested it on a few test cases and it worked, because the optimal sub-solutions *might* appear in the restricted subsets which you check.

Of course, you could expand your solution to check for *all* parenthetizations. In that case, though, you'll reach the regular conclusion for the (straightforward version of the) dynamic programming solution for this problem - filling up the $n^2$ entries needed for the solution takes $\Theta\left(n^3\right)$ time.